# How to inspect application URI link in browser before opening in native application?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet, links, microsoft-teams

I want to inspect the application links used in microsoft teams and other video call apps to join a meeting in the desktop application. My problem is that in the browser the only option I have to open the link but not see what the link actually is. The only option I have is to select an application.
[This is my only option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri6ES.png)

Is there any browser extension or way to get the link before it opens in the application?